# How to set more separation for certain latex symbols

Tags: math-mode, spacing

In the following LaTeX code, `x` and `\widetilde` and `\mathcal{G}_i` are too close.

```
T(x\:\widetilde{\in}\:\mathcal{G}_i)
```

I feel wired because it remains so even if `\:` is added. What is the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to want `\widetilde{\in}` to be a relation symbol; but the problem is that accenting a symbol makes it to lose its type and produces something treated as an ordinary symbol. This can be cured by explicitly making the object a math relation

```
T(x\mathrel{\widetilde{\in}}\mathcal{G}_i)
```

Better defining a new command, then.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\win}{\mathrel{\widetilde{\in}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
T(x\win\mathcal{G}_i) \\
T(x\in\mathcal{G}_i)
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\win` and not `\lose`?