# Missing { inserted. [...mathrel{\stackon[-5pt]{$\in$}{$\widetilde$}] on a question

Tags: math-mode, errors, stacking-symbols, stackengine

For this question [How to set more separation for certain latex symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636185/how-to-set-more-separation-for-certain-latex-symbols) I have given this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}

\[
T(x \mathrel{\stackon[-5pt]{$\in$}{$\widetilde$}} \mathcal{G}_i)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

> Why I have this error: Missing { inserted. [...mathrel{\stackon[-5pt]{$\in$}{$\widetilde$}]?

Comment: Maybe you just missed [this comment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60592453#60592453) in the chat? It is explained there.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `$T(x \mathrel{\widetilde{\in}} \mathcal{G}_i)$`?

Comment: @Mico It is true :-( I wanted create another answer.....:_((((((

Comment: @mickep Thank you for your advice. :-) Grazieeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$\widetilde$`  is `$\widetilede{$}` so the base of the accent is an unmatched `$` and there is no `$` closing the math. TeX can not really recover from this in any reasonable way.

You could use `$\widetilde{}$` so the accent has an empty base, but why put the accent on nothing and then move it with box commands rather than put the accent on the intended base?

Comment: You have right.